HTML videos not showing in instagram app browser
On my website I have video:
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="block w-full h-full object-cover">
    <source src="/img/<?php echo $tmeta->zdjecie; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support video.
</video>

When I open the page in the Instagram app (by clicking on the link in the profile) the video does not display.
If I open the page in a normal browser (Safari, Chrome, etc) everything works.
Have you encountered such a problem?
@edit:
If I click on the link in the Facebook application, the video displays normally (the website also opens in webview).

UPDATE:

I managed get it working with Video.js
This is the code:
HTML & SCRIPTS:
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.21.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.21.1/video.min.js"></script>

<video id="my-video" controls preload="auto" autoplay muted playsinline loop data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/main_.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

JAVASCRIPT
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const player = videojs('my-video', {
        autoplay: false,     // Set to false initially to control autoplay with JavaScript
        muted: true,         // Mute to ensure autoplay compatibility
        loop: true,
        controls: false,  // Disables the control bar
    });
    
    // Manually trigger playback when the player is ready
    player.ready(() => {
        player.play().catch(error => {
            console.log("Autoplay blocked:", error);
            // Fallback if autoplay is blocked
            // You could add a play button overlay here if needed
        });
    });
});
</script>

SUMARY
Autoplay with .play(): Tries to play the video when the player is ready.
Retry / Fallbacks with visibilitychange: These additional methods allow the user to start playback if autoplay fails initially, improving compatibility across different browsers and environments.
Using these techniques give you a reliable playback experience even in environments with strict autoplay policies, like Instagram’s in-app browser.

Same problem here.
I been searching for a solution, but I have only a partial fix.
The first time you enter to the url from the description of the profile on instagram all work with the following simple code.
<script>
    //trigger autoplay video, define video ID to target play action
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#videoclip").trigger('play');
    });
</script>

If you refresh or navigate on the website, and after return to the home page the video don't show up. I have tried everything, simulating click on button to play the video, deleting the autoplay tag and then calling play action with Javascript, but all is blocked but the autoplay policy of the browser. See the following video:
Proofing autoplay video
My understanding was that if the video is muted, it does not violate any autoplay policy.
Check the profile of BMW Spain on Instagram, inside the linktree in the section "NUESTRA WEB" the video of the website is not autoplaying, using the in-app web viewer of instagram: BMW ESPAÑA Instagram
